# Pastebin API Paste Data

Tags: php, pastebin

I've been trying to get the pastebin API to instead of telling me the pastebin link , just output the raw data. The PHP code is this :

```
<?php

$api_dev_key        = 'Stackoverflow(fake key)';    
$api_paste_code         = 'API.'; // your paste text
$api_paste_private      = '1'; // 0=public 1=unlisted 2=private
$api_paste_expire_date  = 'N';
$api_paste_format       = 'php';
$api_paste_code     = urlencode($api_paste_code);

$url            = 'http://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php';
$ch             = curl_init($url);

?>
```

Normally this would upload the $api_paste_code into pastebin , showing up like pastebin.com/St4ck0v3RFL0W , but instead I want it to generate the raw data.

The raw data link is http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=  , can anyone help?

Reference : http://pastebin.com/api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, please note that you must send a `POST` request to the pastebin.com API, not `GET`. So don't use `urlencode()` on your input data!

To get the raw paste url from the page url, you have several options. But the easiest is probably:

```
$apiResonse = 'http://pastebin.com/ABC123';
$raw        = str_replace('m/', 'm/raw.php?i=', $apiResponse);
```

Finally, here is a complete example:

```
<?php
$data = 'Hello World!';

$apiKey  = 'xxxxxxx';                         // get it from pastebin.com
$apiHost = 'http://pastebin.com/';

$postData = array(
    'api_dev_key'    => $apiKey,             // your dev key
    'api_option'     => 'paste',             // action to perform
    'api_paste_code' => utf8_decode($data),  // the paste text
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL             => "{$apiHost}api/api_post.php",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => 1,
    CURLOPT_POST            => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => http_build_query($postData),
));

$result = curl_exec($ch); // on success, some string like 'http://pastebin.com/ABC123'
curl_close($ch);

if ($result) {
    $pasteId = str_replace($apiHost, '', $result);
    $rawLink = "{$apiHost}raw.php?i={$pasteId}";

    echo "Created new paste.\r\n Paste ID:\t{$pasteId}\r\n Page Link:\t{$result}\r\n Raw Link:\t{$rawLink}\r\n";
}
```

Running the above code, outputs:

```
c:\xampp\htdocs>php pastebin.php
Created new paste.
 Paste ID:      Bb8Ehaa7
 Page Link:     http://pastebin.com/Bb8Ehaa7
 Raw Link:      http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Bb8Ehaa7
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see, the response contains the Pastebin URL generated when the content is created. An Url like this:

```
http://pastebin.com/UIFdu235s
```

So what you only need is to get rid of "http://pastebin.com/" doing:

```
$id = str_replace("http://pastebin.com/", "", $url_received_on_last_step);
```

And then, append it to the raw url you provided:

```
$url_raw = "http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=".$id;
```

And you'll get the raw data.

Comment: But where did you get the `$url_received_on_last_step`? I can't see on your code (from the image provided) that you've actually fetch the url received.